# empty condition in elsif section

Tags: ruby

Can you explain what expression use ruby in "elsif" if expression is empty ?

```
arg = 3
if (arg == 1)
  puts "1"
elsif (arg == 2)
  puts "2"
elsif
  puts "3"
end

p (1...10).map { |i|
  if (i == 1)
    1
  elsif (i == 2)
    2
  elsif
    3
  end
}
```

Script output:

```
3
[1, 2, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically there is more to say:

In `if-else` branching, whenever any match condition has been found,then last statement of the matched clause has been returned by the `if-else` block. consider the below:

```
arg = 4
p m = if (arg == 1)
   "1"
elsif (arg == 3)
   "3"
elsif (arg ==4)
   "5";"11"
elsif
   "3"
end
```

*output:*

```
#11
```

But during matching with each clause if any bare `elsif` found then `if-else` block  checks the truth value of its immediate expression and returned the value accordingly:

```
arg = "4"
p m = if (arg == "1")
   47
elsif 
   10 ; "7" 
elsif (arg =="5")
   12;14
elsif
   2
end
```

***Output:***

```
#"7"
```

Below code will return `nil` as nothing to return as `10` is used as condition checking,after that nothing in the code. so `nil` has been returned.

```
arg = "4"
p m = if (arg == "1")
   47
elsif 
   10 
elsif (arg =="5")
   12;14
elsif
   2
end  #nil
```

another code below to make things finally clear:

```
arg = "4"
p m = if (arg == "1")
   47
elsif 
   nil 
elsif (arg =="5")
   12;14
elsif
   2 ; "44"
end  #44
```

With all examples said,above I hope the reason is clear why - the below code outputs: `[1, 2, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]`

```
p (1...10).map { |i|
  if (i == 1)
    1
  elsif (i == 2)
    2
  elsif
    3
  end
}
```

To answer your first code,first take a look at the below two:

```
m = if puts "hi"
p "hello"
end #"hi"
```

"hi" is printed as `puts` returns `nil` on which `if` clause evaluated to `false` thus `hello` is not printed. But the below code does as `p` is used there and `if` clause got executed on the `p` return value which is `true`.

```
m = if p "hi"
p "hello"
end 

#"hi"
#"hello"
```

Now hope you understood why `3` is coming as output from the below code,from the above all logic applied as a whole:

```
arg = 3
if (arg == 1)
  puts "1"
elsif (arg == 2)
  puts "2"
elsif
  puts "3"
end
```

Comment: Interesting, the reason that OP's second example is returning nill for all other cases, is because its treating 3 like the conditional to enter into an empty block.  Whereas the print statement in the first is executed as the conditional printing out the value, but still returning nil

Answer (score 3):

If there is no expression on the same line, the expression from the next line is used as the condition. You cannot have an empty expression.

Your first example is equivalent to this:

```
arg = 3
if (arg == 1)
  puts "1"
elsif (arg == 2)
  puts "2"
elsif puts "3" # puts is the condition
  #empty
end
```

Neither the first or second conditions are true, and since [`puts` returns `nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) neither is the last. However `puts` prints its arguments before returning `nil`, so you still see `3` in the output.

Similarly, your second example is equivalent to:

```
p (1...10).map { |i|
  if (i == 1)
    1
  elsif (i == 2)
    2
  elsif 3
    nil #nil is the default if no result is specified
  end
}
```

Since in Ruby anything that isn’t `false` or `nil` evaluates as `true` in a conditional, the last `elsif` always evaluates to true (`3` isn’t false or nil), and effectively acts like a plain `else`. Also the default value returned is `nil` if nothing is specified, so you see `nil`s in your result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you want to know if the element you're iterating is blank rather that just a fall through for having not matched previous evaluations:

```
elsif i.blank?
```

If you want a catch-all, then just use:

```
else
```